# C# Abstract Class Error

Tags: c#, abstract

```
public abstract class IEnvelopeFactory {

    public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue<IEnvelopeFactory>;

    public IEnvelopeFactory() { }

    ~IEnvelopeFactory() { }

    public virtual void Dispose() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parsing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="envelope"></param>
    public abstract bool Parse(string input, out Envelope envelope);

    /// <summary>
    /// Formatting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="env"></param>
    /// <param name="envStr"></param>
    public abstract bool Format(Envelope env, out string envStr);
}
```

I am getting an error as Syntax Error '(' expected in 
the Line public Queue m_Queue;

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with it being an abstract class. It's just an invalid variable declaration:

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue<IEnvelopeFactory>;
```

What did you expect the second `<IEnvelopeFactory>` to do? It's specifying the generic type argument for `Queue<T>`. It should just be:

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue;
```

... although ideally you wouldn't have a public field in the first place.

(I'd also recommend *against* adding a finalizer just for the sake of it. Finalizers are *very* rarely needed. Also, if you're going to have a `Dispose` method, why aren't you implementing `IDisposable`?)

Comment: That is an answer that adds value

Comment: Hi i am getting some error in other classe files like - 
does not implement inherited abstract member 'CCN.MSG.ENV.IEnvelopeFactory.Format

Comment: @DineshKumarBalaSubramanian: Well then you should implement it... that's a completely different error. Look at it more closely yourself, and you *really* can't fix it, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to:

```
public abstract class IEnvelopeFactory {    
    public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already specified the type strongly, no need to add the generic part to the variable name:

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue;
```

Answer (score 0):

make `m_Queue<IEnvelopeFactory>` => `m_Queue`

In other words:

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue;
```

if you don't want, for some reason, initialize it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it should be:

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue = new Queue<IEnvelopeFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to -

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue;
```

Syntax of Queue class -

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
public class Queue<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, 
    IEnumerable
```

You can define a reference variable in class as -

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue;
```

You can initialize Queue variable in class -

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue = new Queue<IEnvelopeFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Queue<IEnvelopeFactory> m_Queue;
```

That's enough: you've already specified the exact type of the `m_Queue` variable.